# How to get parent thread while debugging asynchronous Java code / Reactive programming

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reactive-programming, reactor

I'm having an issue where asynchronous Java / reactive programming code is harder to debug than synchronous Java code.

Let's say an error message led you to an area in your code:

`2022-02-14T02:11:36.860Z - DEBUG [lw.grpc.main-11:test.local.MyClass@134] - Job 'nick' status 'RUNNING'`

So you put a break point on that particular line `test.local.MyClass@134` then run the debugger.

You get to the breakpoint, but here is your thread:

```
at test.local.MyClass$$Lambda$1843.302025300.accept(Unknown Source:-1)
      
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:196)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmit(FluxFlatMap.java:543)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:984)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:497)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.request(FluxOnAssembly.java:497)
      at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:481)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnAssembly.java:481)
      at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
      at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
      at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
      at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
      at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The debugger has no reference back to the original thread who spawned this request.

I end up scouring the code then for a while before finding the creator of the thread.

But I feel like whilst debugging IntelliJ might be able to do more to help me find the originator of an async thread.

Is there something more than can be done to add a "Parent Thread" so that I can trace back to the thread who spawned this async thread (if it is still alive)?

Comment: You might also find the Reactor debug mode feature helpful https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reactor.html or the async annotations https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-asynchronous-code.html

Comment: yeah this question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100118/debugging-a-spring-webflux-reactor-application-with-intellij-idea thanks tim